# Parse JSON Object from MongoDB GET

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I have a ReactApp with a MongoDB based on local events here in my city. The current schema looks like this.

```
const eventSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  start: String,
  end: String,
  name: String,
  loc: { // Reference: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/geojson.html
    type: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['Point']
    },
    coordinates: {
      type: [Number]
    }
  },
  web: String,
  desc: String
});
```

I have an event button where I press, it gets the data from the DB and renders it to the HTML Page

```
  callbackGetData() {
    fetch('/api')
    .then(resp => {
      console.log(resp);
      return resp.json();
    })
    .then(jdat => {
      console.log(jdat);
      this.setState({ data: JSON.stringify(jdat)}); // Print to debug area.
      // todo: Update marker on the map?
    });
  }
```

when printed on the screen, this the results from the JSON objects that are stored in the database

```
[{"loc":{"coordinates":[-122.698687,45.526974],"type":"Point"},"_id":"5e5c3cde56138449ec49905f","start":".","end":".","name":"Portland Dining Month","web":".","desc":".","__v":0},
{"loc":{"coordinates":[-122.680712,45.509871],"type":"Point"},"_id":"5e5c3cde56138449ec499060","start":".","end":".","name":"Test event @PSU","web":".","desc":".","__v":0},
{"loc":{"coordinates":[-122.674043,45.481716],"type":"Point"},"_id":"5e5c3cde56138449ec499057","start":".","end":".","name":"Transgender Clients: Assessment and Planning for Gender-affirming Medical Procedures","web":".","desc":".","__v":0}]
```

If I try to go and print it with

```
console.log(jdat);
this.setState({ data: JSON.stringify(jdat.name)});
```

It says that it undefined. How can I go about printing out just the individual names and location coordinates and storing them in a variable I can use elsewhere in the file? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a array of data coming from database. so trying `jdat.name` will not work. You need to iterate over the array.

try the following code.Hope you are looking for the same

```js
var jdat = [{"loc":{"coordinates":[-122.698687,45.526974],"type":"Point"},"_id":"5e5c3cde56138449ec49905f","start":".","end":".","name":"Portland Dining Month","web":".","desc":".","__v":0},
{"loc":{"coordinates":[-122.680712,45.509871],"type":"Point"},"_id":"5e5c3cde56138449ec499060","start":".","end":".","name":"Test event @PSU","web":".","desc":".","__v":0},
{"loc":{"coordinates":[-122.674043,45.481716],"type":"Point"},"_id":"5e5c3cde56138449ec499057","start":".","end":".","name":"Transgender Clients: Assessment and Planning for Gender-affirming Medical Procedures","web":".","desc":".","__v":0}]

jdat.forEach(item =>{
  console.log("Name : ",item.name)
  console.log("Location Coordinates : ",item.loc.coordinates)
})
```

Comment: Your answer hardcodes the ```jdat``` with the array. Does it still work the same if it is hardcoded or not?

Comment: Yeah it should work.You only have mentioned the same data so I setted it up the same to a variable.

Comment: If I wanted to loop thru each item or access a specfic item, could I go ```console.log("Name: ", item[0].name);``` ? I get an error when I do

Comment: obviously item[0] will give you the error. item is not an array it is now an object which you can directly access like item.name or item .loc.coordinates. You can use the same as jdat[0].name because jdat is an array

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Thank you